# Can you help me to understand this simple code? R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been learning R the last days and I was solve a exercise of data analysis...
I have a data frame like:

```
   Order_ID Product                 
      <dbl> <chr>                   
 1   319631 34in Ultrawide Monitor  
 2   319631 Lightning Charging Cable
 3   319596 iPhone                  
 4   319596 Lightning Charging Cable
 5   319584 iPhone                  
 6   319584 Wired Headphones        
 7   319556 Google Phone            
 8   319556 Wired Headphones        
 9   319536 Macbook Pro Laptop
```

with products purchased by some client (ORDER_ID). I want to know which pair of products are sold more frequently so, after a few hours of google, I found this:

```
Sales_Duplicated <- Sales[duplicated(Sales$Order_ID) | duplicated(Sales$Order_ID, fromLast=TRUE), 1:2] #I get the rows with duplicate Order_ID
Sales_Duplicated$Order_ID <- as.numeric(Sales_Duplicated$Order_ID)
Sales_Duplicated <- arrange(Sales_Duplicated, desc(Order_ID))

### I find the pairs
Sold_Together <- Sales_Duplicated %>%
  widyr::pairwise_count(feature = Order_ID, item = Product) %>%
  filter(item1 > item2) %>%
  mutate(Pair = paste(item1, item2, sep = "/")) %>%
  dplyr::select(Pair, Count = n)

arrange(Sold_Together, desc(Count)) # and I sort its
```

So, the code works but I can't understand completely how works. My questions are about the `filter()`:

1. What is the `filter()` function for?
2. What means the `filter1 > filter2`?

Someone can teach me? Thanks a lot.

EDIT: I add some extra code

```
Sales_Duplicated %>%
  widyr::pairwise_count(feature = Order_ID, item = Product)

   item1                    item2                      n
   <chr>                    <chr>                  <dbl>
 1 Lightning Charging Cable 34in Ultrawide Monitor    33
 2 iPhone                   34in Ultrawide Monitor    13
 3 Wired Headphones         34in Ultrawide Monitor    28
 4 Google Phone             34in Ultrawide Monitor     5
 5 Macbook Pro Laptop       34in Ultrawide Monitor     7
```

```
Sales_Duplicated %>%
  widyr::pairwise_count(feature = Order_ID, item = Product) %>%
  filter(item1 > item2)

   item1                      item2                      n
   <chr>                      <chr>                  <dbl>
 1 Lightning Charging Cable   34in Ultrawide Monitor    33
 2 iPhone                     34in Ultrawide Monitor    13
 3 Wired Headphones           34in Ultrawide Monitor    28
 4 Google Phone               34in Ultrawide Monitor     5
 5 Macbook Pro Laptop         34in Ultrawide Monitor     7
```

```
Sales_Duplicated %>%
  widyr::pairwise_count(feature = Order_ID, item = Product) %>%
  filter(item1 > item2) %>%
  mutate(Pair = paste(item1, item2, sep = "/"))

   item1                      item2                      n Pair                                             
   <chr>                      <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>                                            
 1 Lightning Charging Cable   34in Ultrawide Monitor    33 Lightning Charging Cable/34in Ultrawide Monitor  
 2 iPhone                     34in Ultrawide Monitor    13 iPhone/34in Ultrawide Monitor                    
 3 Wired Headphones           34in Ultrawide Monitor    28 Wired Headphones/34in Ultrawide Monitor          
 4 Google Phone               34in Ultrawide Monitor     5 Google Phone/34in Ultrawide Monitor              
 5 Macbook Pro Laptop         34in Ultrawide Monitor     7 Macbook Pro Laptop/34in Ultrawide Monitor
```

And finally

```
Sales_Duplicated %>%
  widyr::pairwise_count(feature = Order_ID, item = Product) %>%
  filter(item1 > item2) %>%
  mutate(Pair = paste(item1, item2, sep = "/")) %>%
  dplyr::select(Pair, Count = n)

   Pair                                              Count
   <chr>                                             <dbl>
 1 Lightning Charging Cable/34in Ultrawide Monitor      33
 2 iPhone/34in Ultrawide Monitor                        13
 3 Wired Headphones/34in Ultrawide Monitor              28
 4 Google Phone/34in Ultrawide Monitor                   5
```

Comment: `filter()` is  a function from `dplyr`  package used to subset rows using column values .

Comment: And `item1` and `item2` could be the column names.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Yes! This solve my previous problem. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011977/how-can-i-identify-and-count-unique-pairs-at-every-level-in-a-list-of-lists-in-r)

Comment: @Ed_Gravy Yes, they are. because the pairwise_count() function create a new table with the count of each pair event